# How to use the Division Algorithm (polynomial rings) and evaluation map to prove the Remainder Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

I am trying to use my proof of the Division Algorithm and evaluation map to prove the Remainder Theorem which states:

Let *F* be a field, *a* in *F*, *f* in *F*[*x*]. Then the remainder when *f* is divided by the polynomial *x* - *a* is equal to *f*(*a*).

I would like some guidance as to where to start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write the **Euclidean division** of $f$ by $(x-a)$
**EDIT**
$$f(x) = Q(x)\cdot\big(x-a\big) + R(x) \textrm{ where } deg(R) < \mathbf{deg(X-a)}$$

What do you get for $f(a)$?

Comment: f(a) = q(a) "times" 0 + r(a) = r(a)

Comment: Oops One had to read "$deg(R)<1$! Hence, $R$ is constant, and you know that $f(a)=R(a)$.